# Macroscopic averaging validity (e.g. density)

Tags: density, molecules, microscopy

When dealing with macroscopic scales, it is common to introduce continuous functions (such as density) which model the behaviour of the underlying microscopic matter.
However, I still can't understand how this approach can be fully justified.

It is often stated that the averaging process is performed over a volume which is big enough to contain a lot of molecules, but small enough with respect to the whole object's size.
I understand what this means, but it seems to me that this is not enough: I imagine that, inside the averaging-volume, the microscopic quantities could change and oscillate very rapidly, possibly assuming values which are very different from the final "brutal average" performed by my macroscopic function.

In this scenario, the macroscopic averaging operation would cause the loss of some important informations regarding the microscopic quantities - a sort of "aliasing" error.

Could you please tell me where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

you are not wrong in the sense that some information is always lost when we describe the system in that way. However, this has always have to be compared with respect to the *questions we ask about the system*, i.e. the quantities that we are trying to calculate. If these quantities have a larger length-scale than the averaging one, then we should be fine with this coarse-graining process.

Usually, in macroscopic systems we are interested in some sort of a macroscopic behavior - response to some external perturbation, of a macroscopic quantity that can be evidenced on large scales. This means that from the onset we are examining some sort of an averaged behavior on a large scale, so microscopic fluctuation below some scale shouldn't concern us: taking them into account will have a negligible effect on the final result.

In addition, these systems usually have a natural correlation length, that depends on temperature, interactions etc. This length-scale tells us how far such microscopic fluctuation can travel and effect other regions before they fizzle out. As long as we average on scales that are not larger than this length scale, we should be alright. Things become more complicated as this length-scale diverges into infinity, indicating a phase-transition, where microscopic fluctuations can affect the entire system. The study of the different scales in the system, and their behavior, is a fascinating subject by itself, with links to [the renormalization group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Renormalization_group) .